# Difference between the jars for spring web services

Tags: spring

I have just started learning on spring  webservices but when I search for the tutorials in some examples they added the following dependency for springwscore and in some examples the following dependency for spring-boot-starter-ws.which jar sholud be used and why spring has two jars for spring web services.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be including dependency by adding Spring Ws Core to Maven pom.xml file (if you are using Maven)

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```